# Chemical that will dissolve the oils left over from broken down coffee grounds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, solubility

When coffee grounds breakdown in pipes there is a black sludge residue as a result. Is there a chemical that would dissolve this residue?

Comment: The obvious answer here is a good “professional strength” commercial drain cleaner: they are formulated to do the job without harming the pipes (whatever they happen to be made of). Maybe it will take multiple applications, but that is far better than risking real problems by using chemicals that are not approved for the purpose. There is also the environmental aspect of the waste stream after the cleaning.

Comment: @EdV Not whatever they're made of - Al pipes can be damaged, for example.

Comment: @Mithoron I was not implying that an arbitrary drain cleaner formulation would work with an arbitrary pipe material: the containers tell purchasers all the usage and safety details. My own house plumbing is a mix of copper pipes, cast iron stand pipe and several types of plastic, but no aluminum. Of course, there are always people who ignore all safety and usage information and mix various bathroom and plumbing chemicals, sometimes with fatal consequences. As well, I seriously doubt aluminum pipe would be legal in homes in the USA.

Comment: @Mithoron, I don't recall any place where aluminum drain pipes are used in kitchen sinks, or washrooms. Nobody would use a highly reactive metal to make pipes for kitchen sink waste which is always alkaline from detergents etc.